# How to resolve CSS background image not loading on a Django template

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

Hey so I am trying to inject a background image to my Django template however for some reason I do not know why it not loading I tried inline styling on the html(** ) tag but nothing

I the tried to to  make an external css file but still not working can you please show me what I can be possibly doing wrong here.

** Below is the code to my html tag that I want to put the background image to**

```
    <div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-start" data-scrollax-parent="true">
      <div class="col-md-6 ftco-animate">
        <h2 class="subheading">Leave the house cleaning chores to us</h2>
        <h1 class="mb-4">Let us do the dirty work, so you don't have to.</h1>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mr-md-4 py-2 px-4">Learn more <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here below is the external css file that I made to test if it would work having an external stylesheet**

```
.hero-wrap js-fullheight{

background-image: url('static/images/bg_1.jpg');
}
```

If possible can you teach me how I can make inline background-image on the html tags using Django templates

Comment: [Django has awesome documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial06/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url({% static '/images/bg_1.jpg' %});">
```